# Facebook implementation in libGDX

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx

I'm developing a game using the libGDX Framework.

I'd like to implement an icon that would make the user like the game on facebook. I've tried the libGDX forums with little to no luck. I'll be very glad if I can get some help on it, or at least be told of a tutorial or explanation link.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook like button is actually just an HTML link. So why not add that to a label or any other area in your game and just open the browser to that URL, or send a POST or GET request if that's possible?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/